What replaces AES_set_decrypt_key and AES_unwrap_key in OpenSSL 3?
The AES_set_decrypt_key and AES_unwrap_key functions are deprecated in OpenSSL 3. I'm maintaining a function which uses them that I'd like to update to use non-deprecated functions:
std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> rfc3394_key_unwrap(const uint8_t* key, size_t key_len,
    const void *input, size_t input_len, const void *iv) noexcept 
{
  AES_KEY aes_key;
  AES_set_decrypt_key(key, key_len * 8, &aes_key);

  const int output_len = input_len - 8;

  auto out = std::make_unique<uint8_t[]>(output_len);

  const auto ret = AES_unwrap_key(&aes_key, (const uint8_t*)iv, out.get(),
                                  (const uint8_t*)input, input_len);

  if (ret != output_len) {
    return nullptr;
  }

  return out;
}

Or, in C if you prefer:
uint8_t* rfc3394_key_unwrap(const uint8_t *key, size_t key_len, const void *input,
    size_t input_len, const void *iv)
{
  AES_KEY aes_key;
  AES_set_decrypt_key(key, key_len * 8, &aes_key);

  const int output_len = input_len - 8;

  uint8_t* out = (uint8_t*) malloc(output_len);

  const int ret = AES_unwrap_key(&aes_key, (const uint8_t*)iv, out,
                                (const uint8_t*)input, input_len);

  if (ret != output_len) {
    free(out);
    return NULL;
  }

  return out;
}

I haven't been able to determine what the replacements are (possibly amongst the EVP_CIPHER functions?). What should I be looking for?

Please don't tag C++ code with C.

Who did say that the functions are deprecated? I'm reading the manual and don't set the deprecation there.

It doesn't matter that the code is C++, because the API I'm asking about is a C API. I'll include a C version of the function for you.

The compiler warning I get from each function says "... is deprecated: Since OpenSSL 3.0".

It's not a vendor change. The two functions I'm asking about are listed as deprecated in the OpenSSL docs on their own site: https://docs.openssl.org/3.0/man7/migration_guide/#deprecated-function-mappings

Any case follow the OpenSSL manual to use the high level API instead that low level API.

That's why I'm asking the question. I don't see how to use the high level API to do that.

You can essentially build on this code, and instead of EVP_aes_256_cbc() you have to use e.g. EVP_aes_256_wrap() (or one of the other AES wrap variants EVP_aes_128_wrap(), EVP_aes_192_wrap(), see here).

If I undersatnd EVP_aes_256_wrap() correctly, it's intended to unwrap the wrapped key and then decrypt with that, without ever giving you the unwrapped key. (Maybe I don't understand it correctly, however.) What I want is the unwrapped key, not to decrypt further cyphertext.

No, you have misunderstood. Decrypting with EVP_aes_256_wrap() gives the decrypted (= unwrapped) key, so it does the same as the function rfc3394_key_unwrap() you posted, see my answer for more details.

The AES Key Unwrap (described in RFC 3394, section 2.2.2) can be implemented with the high level functions (EVP_...) like an ordinary decryption, e.g. as described here in the OpenSSL Wiki, where only instead of EVP_aes_256_cbc() (for decryption with AES-256/CBC) one of the Key Wrap ciphers, e.g. EVP_aes_256_wrap() (for an AES-256 Key Unwrap) is to be used, as shown below (for the sake of simplicity without exception handling):
int decrypt(unsigned char* ciphertext, int ciphertext_len, unsigned char* key, unsigned char* iv, unsigned char* plaintext)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX* ctx;
    int len;
    int plaintext_len;

    ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_wrap(), NULL, key, iv);

    EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plaintext, &len, ciphertext, ciphertext_len);
    plaintext_len = len;

    EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, plaintext + len, &len);
    plaintext_len += len;

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    return plaintext_len;
}

Here, ciphertext is the wrapped (= encrypted) key and plaintext is the original (= unwrapped/decrypted) key.
Example with the test vector from RFC 3394, 4.3:
unsigned char wrapping_key[] = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17, 0x18, 0x19, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x1c, 0x1d, 0x1e, 0x1f };
unsigned char wrapped_key[] = { 0x64, 0xe8, 0xc3, 0xf9, 0xce, 0x0f, 0x5b, 0xa2, 0x63, 0xe9, 0x77, 0x79, 0x05, 0x81, 0x8a, 0x2a, 0x93, 0xc8, 0x19, 0x1e, 0x7d, 0x6e, 0x8a, 0xe7 };
unsigned char iv[] = { 0xa6, 0xa6, 0xa6, 0xa6, 0xa6, 0xa6, 0xa6, 0xa6 }; // default IV for key wrap

unsigned char unwrapped_key[16];
int unwrapped_key_len = decrypt(wrapped_key, sizeof(wrapped_key), wrapping_key, iv, unwrapped_key);
// hex dump of unwrapped_key: 00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff

The rfc3394_key_unwrap() function you posted gives the same result for the same input data!
The following also applies:

If you pass NULL as IV in decrypt(), the default IV for Key Wrap/Unwrap is used: 0xa6a6a6a6a6a6a6a6.
As of OpenSSL v3 there is no need to set the EVP_CIPHER_CTX_FLAG_WRAP_ALLOW flag, s. this post.


I was so close! I had this, but with the iv and key arguments reversed. Thank you so much.

It certainly appears that OpenSSL documentation almost completely missed covering this.
The only mention of AES_wrap_key() and AES_unwrap_key() in the OpenSSL 3.0 Migration Guide is this:


AES_unwrap_key(), AES_wrap_key()

See "Deprecated low-level encryption functions"

As this answer is written, though, that Deprectead low-level encryption functions section omits any mention of either AES_wrap_key() or AES_unwrap_key().
However, the current (as of Oct 15, 2024) OpenSSL source code for AES_wrap_key() and AES_unwrap_key() is:
/*
 * Copyright 2008-2020 The OpenSSL Project Authors. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License 2.0 (the "License").  You may not use
 * this file except in compliance with the License.  You can obtain a copy
 * in the file LICENSE in the source distribution or at
 * https://www.openssl.org/source/license.html
 */

/*
 * AES_encrypt/AES_decrypt are deprecated - but we need to use them to implement
 * these functions
 */
#include "internal/deprecated.h"

#include "internal/cryptlib.h"
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <openssl/modes.h>

int AES_wrap_key(AES_KEY *key, const unsigned char *iv,
                 unsigned char *out,
                 const unsigned char *in, unsigned int inlen)
{
    return CRYPTO_128_wrap(key, iv, out, in, inlen, (block128_f) AES_encrypt);
}

int AES_unwrap_key(AES_KEY *key, const unsigned char *iv,
                   unsigned char *out,
                   const unsigned char *in, unsigned int inlen)
{
    return CRYPTO_128_unwrap(key, iv, out, in, inlen,
                             (block128_f) AES_decrypt);
}

The OpenSSL source code for CRYPTO_128_wrap() has this comment:
/** Wrapping according to RFC 3394 section 2.2.1.

So you need to do RFC 3394 key wrapping/unwrapping.
And OpenSSL demo code provides a key wrap/unwrap example. although there's no explicit reference to RFC 3394.
The relevant wrapping code appears to be
/* Create a context for the encrypt operation */
if ((ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()) == NULL)
    goto err;

EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_flags(ctx, EVP_CIPHER_CTX_FLAG_WRAP_ALLOW);

/* Fetch the cipher implementation */
if ((cipher = EVP_CIPHER_fetch(libctx, "AES-256-WRAP", propq)) == NULL)
    goto err;

/*
 * Initialise an encrypt operation with the cipher/mode, key and IV.
 * We are not setting any custom params so let params be just NULL.
 */
if (!EVP_EncryptInit_ex2(ctx, cipher, wrap_key, wrap_iv, /* params */ NULL))
    goto err;

/* Encrypt plaintext */
if (!EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, outbuf, &outlen, wrap_pt, sizeof(wrap_pt)))
    goto err;

/* Finalise: there can be some additional output from padding */
if (!EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, outbuf + outlen, &tmplen))
    goto err;
outlen += tmplen;

I suspect you'd have to use "AES-128-WRAP" instead of "AES-256-WRAP".
Then there is the EVP_aes_128_wrap() cipher, which do explicitly mention RFC 3394:


EVP_aes_128_wrap(), EVP_aes_192_wrap(), EVP_aes_256_wrap(), EVP_aes_128_wrap_pad(), EVP_aes_192_wrap_pad(), EVP_aes_256_wrap_pad()

AES key wrap with 128, 192 and 256 bit keys, as according to RFC 3394 section 2.2.1 ("wrap") and RFC 5649 section 4.1 ("wrap with padding") respectively.

I suspect that way to use that would be to replace the call to EVP_CIPHER_fetch() in the OpenSSL demo code with a call to EVP_aes_128_wrap().

The example in the demo looks like it's doing complete decryption, whereas what I want is the wrapped key only,
